# How to authenticate to Azure Devops by using token of an Application ID(service principal)?

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, token

I have an Azure Devops pipeline where i have automated the creation of a service connection for azure subscriptions and also triggering the stage 2 of the pipeline. For the moment, the pipeline tasks authenticates to Azure Devops by using **PAT**. **I don't want to use PAT** because it depends to a person and cannot automate its regeneration. So I have seen that I can authenticate with `Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tokens`. Here there is [a tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops#authenticate-with-azure-active-directory-azure-ad-tokens) of Microsoft. So i have created an `app registration` and given him to **Azure Devops user_impersonation API permission** . I have also create `azure web app service` to run the python application. I have changed the `app_config.py` with the application ID and the secret:

```
import os

# To configure this application, fill in your application (client) ID, client secret, 
# AAD tenant ID, and Azure DevOps collection name in the placeholders below.

CLIENT_ID = "xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" 
# Application (client) ID of app registration

CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
# In a production app, we recommend you use a more secure method of storing your secret,
# like Azure Key Vault. Or, use an environment variable as described in Flask's documentation:
# https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-environment-variables
# CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
# if not CLIENT_SECRET:
#     raise ValueError("Need to define CLIENT_SECRET environment variable")

# AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/Enter_the_Tenant_ID_Here"  # For multi-tenant app
AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx"

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # Used for forming an absolute URL to your redirect URI.
                              # The absolute URL must match the redirect URI you set
                              # in the app's registration in the Azure portal.

ENDPOINT = 'https://vssps.dev.azure.com/myorg/_apis/Tokens/Pats?api-version=6.1-preview' 
# fill in the url to the user's ADO collection name here

SCOPE = ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default"]
# Means "All scopes for the Azure DevOps API resource"

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  
# Specifies the token cache should be stored in server-side session
```

So the application is running succesfully. **But the thing is that the application is asking me to sign in**:
[image]

This is what i wanted to avoid at the beginning. Why it is asking me "login" although i have provided app id and its secret in app_config.py?

UPDATE:
I have used [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) as @suomi-dev suggested. I am able to produce a bearer token, i am not able to authenticate to azure devops. Here is the response, i get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">




<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>

        Azure DevOps Services | Sign In

    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11;&#32;IE=10;&#32;IE=9;&#32;IE=8" />
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/favicon.ico" />

    <link data-bundlelength="508992" data-bundlename="commoncss"
        data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-commoncss-v6u3Ge4AQ3uP84WaM1_W6QGvjulv0ohK4twlMPGNhjUY="
        data-includedstyles="jQueryUI-Modified;Core;Splitter;PivotView"
        href="/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-commoncss-vHQmPgPp5spmzbH-BlYoXG_Hn35TPVL28elmFhmVVmDU="
        rel="stylesheet" />
    <link data-bundlelength="116278" data-bundlename="viewcss"
        data-highcontrast="/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_cssbundles/HighContrast/vss-bundle-viewcss-vfceofgWpooCKNRb2b7qGygIv-1cQRzxrP0B4pEtwImw="
        data-includedstyles="VSS.Controls"
        href="/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-viewcss-vXgT3Z4VlQs_ppchNra9ZkzNQE6bqAzibhdP4ooPkmWU="
        rel="stylesheet" />

    <!--UxServices customizations -->

    <link href="/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_content/Authentication.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body class="platform">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __vssPageContext = {"webContext":{"user":{"id":"aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa","name":"Anonymous","email":"","uniqueName":"TEAM FOUNDATION\\Anonymous"},"host":{"id":"7d0cc8e9-39e8-4313-9ff3-23ace0f8f4cf","name":"TEAM FOUNDATION","uri":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/","relativeUri":"/","hostType":"deployment","scheme":"https","authority":"spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com"}},"moduleLoaderConfig":{"baseUrl":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/","paths":{"Profile/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","VSS/Resources":"en-US","Account/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","UserManagement/Scripts/Resources":"en-US","Authentication/Scripts/Resources":"en-US"},"map":{},"contributionPaths":{"VSS":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/VSS","pathType":"default"},"VSS/Resources":{"value":"en-US","pathType":"resource"},"q":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/q","pathType":"default"},"knockout":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/knockout","pathType":"default"},"mousetrap":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/mousetrap","pathType":"default"},"mustache":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/mustache","pathType":"default"},"react":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/react.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-dom":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/react-dom.15.3","pathType":"default"},"react-transition-group":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/react-transition-group.15.3","pathType":"default"},"jQueryUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/jQueryUI","pathType":"default"},"jquery":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/jquery","pathType":"default"},"OfficeFabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/OfficeFabric","pathType":"default"},"tslib":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/tslib","pathType":"default"},"@uifabric":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/@uifabric","pathType":"default"},"VSSUI":{"value":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/VSSUI","pathType":"default"}},"shim":{"jquery":{"deps":[],"exports":"jQuery"}},"waitSeconds":30},"coreReferences":{"stylesheets":[{"url":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_cssbundles/Default/vss-bundle-ext-core-css-vNmgDWCLCX0sHlt44FFqt9QrKVBLhz4rqsgP12zXSp8g=","highContrastUrl":null,"isCoreStylesheet":true}],"scripts":[{"identifier":"JQuery","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"JQueryXDomain","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"Promise","url":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/promise.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"GlobalScripts","url":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/min/global-scripts.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/pre-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false},{"identifier":"AMDLoader","url":"/_static/3rdParty/_scripts/require.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},{"identifier":"LoaderFixes","url":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_scripts/TFS/post-loader-shim.min.js","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":false}],"coreScriptsBundle":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-v9GpWWBnsWqhM23ijhK2HfAqLowTXGUqZLDRsBCZbkfY=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true},"extensionCoreReferences":{"identifier":"CoreBundle","url":"/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-ext-core-vIzSYLPJCTdYZH2THb6MmQ8IGqUykR9674vJI83Yv4xM=","fallbackUrl":null,"fallbackCondition":null,"isCoreModule":true}},"webAccessConfiguration":{"isHosted":true,"paths":{"rootPath":"/","staticContentRootPath":"/","staticContentVersion":"M188_20210614.1","resourcesPath":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_content/","staticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/","cdnFallbackStaticRootTfs":"/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/","staticRoot3rdParty":"/_static/3rdParty/"},"api":{"webApiVersion":"1","areaPrefix":"_","controllerPrefix":""},"mailSettings":{"enabled":false},"registryItems":{}},"microsoftAjaxConfig":{"cultureInfo":{"name":"en-US","numberFormat":{"CurrencyDecimalDigits":2,"CurrencyDecimalSeparator":".","IsReadOnly":true,"CurrencyGroupSizes":[3],"NumberGroupSizes":[3],"PercentGroupSizes":[3],"CurrencyGroupSeparator":",","CurrencySymbol":"$","NaNSymbol":"NaN","CurrencyNegativePattern":0,"NumberNegativePattern":1,"PercentPositivePattern":1,"PercentNegativePattern":1,"NegativeInfinitySymbol":"-∞","NegativeSign":"-","NumberDecimalDigits":2,"NumberDecimalSeparator":".","NumberGroupSeparator":",","CurrencyPositivePattern":0,"PositiveInfinitySymbol":"∞","PositiveSign":"+","PercentDecimalDigits":2,"PercentDecimalSeparator":".","PercentGroupSeparator":",","PercentSymbol":"%","PerMilleSymbol":"‰","NativeDigits":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],"DigitSubstitution":1},"dateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"AM","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00","MaxSupportedDateTime":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":"/","FirstDayOfWeek":0,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt","LongDatePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy","LongTimePattern":"h:mm:ss tt","MonthDayPattern":"MMMM d","PMDesignator":"PM","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'","ShortDatePattern":"M/d/yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"h:mm tt","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"],"ShortestDayNames":["Su","Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa"],"DayNames":["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""],"IsReadOnly":true,"NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December",""]},"numberShortForm":{"QuantitySymbols":["K","M","B"],"NumberGroupSize":1000,"ThousandSymbol":"K"},"eras":null}},"timeZonesConfiguration":{},"featureAvailability":{"featureStates":{"VisualStudio.Services.Contribution.EnableOnPremUnsecureBrowsers":false,"VisualStudio.Service.WebPlatform.ClientErrorReporting":false,"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Gallery.Client.UseCdnAssetUri":false,"VisualStudio.Services.WebAccess.SubresourceIntegrity":false,"VisualStudio.Services.IdentityPicker.ReactProfileCard":true}},"appInsightsConfiguration":{"enabled":false,"instrumentationKey":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","insightsScriptUrl":null},"diagnostics":{"sessionId":"91ddbf13-332e-4719-965a-6d5f16a576b5","activityId":"91ddbf13-332e-4719-965a-6d5f16a576b5","bundlingEnabled":true,"webPlatformVersion":"M188","serviceVersion":"Dev18.M188.1 (build: AzureDevOps_M188_20210614.1)"},"navigation":{"topMostLevel":"deployment","area":"","currentController":"Signin","currentAction":"Index","routeId":"LegacyWebAccessRoute","routeValues":{"controller":"Signin","action":"Index"}},"globalization":{"explicitTheme":"","theme":"Default","culture":"en-US","timezoneOffset":0,"timeZoneId":"UTC"},"serviceInstanceId":"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381","hubsContext":{},"serviceLocations":{"locations":{"951917ac-a960-4999-8464-e3f0aa25b381":{"Application":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/","Deployment":"https://spsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com/"}}}};
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var __cultureInfo = __vssPageContext.microsoftAjaxConfig.cultureInfo;
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-basejs'); }
    </script>
    <script data-bundlelength="125076" data-bundlename="basejs"
        src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-basejs-v9GpWWBnsWqhM23ijhK2HfAqLowTXGUqZLDRsBCZbkfY="
        type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-basejs'); }
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        require.config(__vssPageContext.moduleLoaderConfig);
    </script>

    <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="4n1E6rTOw8fc0z_SO8fzjPWwH2GntNK14JNwSy_b6-63D4AUIHexBvld_xy8utkCB5esKsyGLQA-05YaMPklaRnZ1881" />






    <div class="account signin main-container hide">


        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="header-section" role="banner">


                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_static/tfs/M188_20210614.1/_content/Combined.css">
                <div id="ux-header" class="FF ltr vsIntegrate" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <span id="isMobile"></span>
                    <div class="upperBand">
                        <div class="upperBandContent">
                            <div class="left"></div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="profileImage"></div>

                                <div id="signIn">
                                    <a class=":SignedOutProfileElement: createProfileLink" href="/go/profile"
                                        title="Anonymous">Anonymous</a>
                                    <a class="scarabLink" href="/_signout">Sign out</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear-both"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-section" role="main">


                <div class="signin-main-content">
                    <noscript>
                        <span class="error">Microsoft Internet Explorer&#39;s Enhanced Security Configuration is currently enabled on your environment. This enhanced level of security prevents our web integration experiences from displaying or performing correctly. To continue with your operation please disable this configuration or contact your administrator.</span>
                    </noscript>
                    <div class="provider-control">
                        <script class="options" defer="defer" type="application/json">
                            {"providerOptions":{"force":false,"orgIdAuthUrl":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/c611881e-e32d-4009-accc-0c1a258b602a/oauth2/authorize?client_id=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798\u0026site_id=501454\u0026response_mode=form_post\u0026response_type=code+id_token\u0026redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fspsprodweu4.vssps.visualstudio.com%2F_signedin\u0026nonce=dae7c29c-fa33-46da-a7d8-3bcbe135a55b\u0026state=realm%3Ddev.azure.com%26reply_to%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.azure.com%252Ftest%252Flab-test%252F_apis%252Fgit%252Frepositories%253Fapi-version%253D6.1-preview.1%26ht%3D2%26hid%3De82482f2-c6c4-429b-bf8a-20a4b358da6f%26nonce%3Ddae7c29c-fa33-46da-a7d8-3bcbe135a55b\u0026resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.core.windows.net%2F\u0026cid=dae7c29c-fa33-46da-a7d8-3bcbe135a55b\u0026wsucxt=1","user":null,"signInContext":"eyJodCI6MiwiaGlkIjoiNWRhZWZkMmEtOGZhNS00NDFlLTgyZWItYjM3OTUwODcxNmZmIiwicXMiOnsicmVhbG0iOiJkZXYuYXp1cmUuY29tIiwicmVwbHlfdG8iOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi5henVyZS5jb20vdGVzdGRhdGF5L2xhYnYyLXRlc3QvX2FwaXMvZ2l0L3JlcG9zaXRvcmllcz9hcGktdmVyc2lvbj02LjEtcHJldmlldy4xIiwiaHQiOiIyIiwiaGlkIjoiZTgyNDgyZjItYzZjNC00MjliLWJmOGEtMjBhNGIzNThkYTZmIiwibm9uY2UiOiJkYWU3YzI5Yy1mYTMzLTQ2ZGEtYTdkOC0zYmNiZTEzNWE1NWIifSwicnIiOiIiLCJ2aCI6IiIsImN2IjoiIiwiY3MiOiIifQ2"}}
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>


        </div>





        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-common'); }
        </script>
        <script data-bundlelength="212619" data-bundlename="common" data-includedscripts="VSS/Bundling"
            src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-common-v9clbQjZeX8SFazwgF3HBRpCw_AYcSBPxtOpkg9Bv2-o="
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-common'); }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('startLoadBundleOuter-view'); }
        </script>
        <script data-bundlelength="159354" data-bundlename="view"
            data-includedscripts="Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls;Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication"
            src="/_public/_Bundling/Content?bundle=vss-bundle-view-vNUGsoXgRUC5b3kr3BUOKazaVcS2VmFUCbEtaFD5SGSA="
            type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('endLoadBundleOuter-view'); }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireStart'); }
require(["Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication.Controls","Authentication/Scripts/SPS.Authentication"], function(){  if (window.performance && window.performance.mark) { window.performance.mark('requireEnd'); } window.requiredModulesLoaded=true;  });
        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

It asks me to sign in. But when i try the same GET request with my PAT, it is working.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. When we add the Azure DevOps API permission in our app registration, we only have the option to add that as a Delegated Permission, the description for which says - Your application needs to access the API as the signed-in user.

Application Permission type is disabled

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access your resource (API endpoint) purely using client id and secret without user authentication, then you are looking for [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) (also known as two legged OAuth). You will also need to give access & roles to your client (app registration) either using [ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#assign-app-roles-to-applications) or application permission assignment through AD.

Once you implement client credentials flow, you will get access token. Then you can use that access token in your subsequest endpoint requests.

I have not done this in python but the concept is same. You can also test this with POSTMAN:

```
// Obtain token using client credentials flow
POST //Line breaks for clarity
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenentId}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=xxxxxxxxxx
&scope=api://499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&client_secret=xxxxxxx
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Above request would give you access token in the reponse body. Then you can use the access token in your subsequent endpoint requests.

This article describes it in more detail: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: i have updated the question. I cannot login to Azure Devops with bearer token. Although i have given permission in AzureAD with user_impersonation. But the thing is that how can i give RBACs to that sp within Azure Devops?

Comment: do you have any update on your issue? I, kind of, face a similar issue.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download [ms-identity-python-webapp](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp) and follow the install instructions.

Add msal, azure-devops and msrest to requirements.txt

```
msal>=1.7,<2
azure-devops==6.0.0b2
msrest==0.6.13
```

In app_config.py change the `SCOPE` to user_impersonation and add your `ADO_URL`

```
SCOPE = ["499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/user_impersonation"]
DEVOPS_URL = 'https://dev.azure.com/<your ADO organisation name here>'
```

In your app.py try the following in `graphcall()`

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import OAuthTokenAuthentication

# Use the MSAL token to generate an ADO OAuth token
credentials = OAuthTokenAuthentication(app_config.CLIENT_ID, token)
connection = Connection(base_url=app_config.DEVOPS_URL, creds=credentials)

# Get a client
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()
```